# Strange results while measuring C++ AMP performance

Tags: c++-amp

I'm wrapping a C++ AMP invocation with [this timer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/12/28/high-resolution-timer-for-c.aspx), with the code shown below. Unfortunately, according to the timer, my C++ AMP call takes about 2 seconds - a lot more than it realistically does. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (int t = 0; t < 20; ++t)
{
  Timer gpuTimer;
  gpuTimer.Start();
  auto gh = gpu_histogram(target, size);
  gpuTimer.Stop();
  sum += gpuTimer.Elapsed();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a simple misunderstanding - I assumed that `Timer` measures time in seconds whereas it's actually using milliseconds. :) Data makes sense now and... C++ AMP is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you have not shared enough code. I can’t tell what gpu_histogram does, or if you are using best practices for [Measuring Performance of C++ AMP computations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/07/26/performance-guidance-for-c-amp.aspx), or if you are adjusting the results of sum for the 20 iterations that the calculation is performed etc. Try posting a complete repro with expected and actual results – btw, the team monitors questions in [our msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelcppnative/threads).